# how to insert a webview inside unity UI layout?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webview

I'm developing an app in unity which to run in iPhone,what I wanna do is to add a webview to show website, then add other UI elements created in unity to cover the webview,is there any way I can do this?Because it seems after adding a webview,it is always shown above everything I created in unity,I can't find a way to position it middle of my UI,is there anyone who has ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/gree/unity-webview

Comment: I've seen that, but running the sample project confuses me, it works exactly the way I want in unity editor,but when I build the project for iOS and run it on my iPhone,the webview just cover everything, it doesn't seem to work.